# R=301, htaccess redirecionar para a nova pagina

Tags: htaccess

Bom eu criei uma pagina com a URL personalizada

```
RewriteRule     ^produtos/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    produto.php?product=$1      [NC,L]
```

bom, ate ai ok, o novo *link* funciona

Porém eu estou tentando bloquear o acesso direto pela URL `produto.php?product=$1`

e se por acaso a pessoa tentar, seja redirecionada para a Nova URL que no caso é `produtos/?NOMEQUEVAISERMANDADO`

Answer (score 0):

Simplesmente tem que criar uma nova regra, se a URL solicitada corresponde a `produto.php`:

```py
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirecionar se acessar diretamente para produto.php
#  a) com o parâmetro ?product=xxxxxx
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}              ^(?:.*&)?product=([a-z0-9-]*)  [NC]
RewriteRule ^produto\.php/?$             produtos/%1  [NC,QSD,R,L]
#  b) sem o parâmetro
RewriteRule ^produto\.php/?$             produtos/    [NC,R,L]

# Reescrita normal
RewriteRule ^produtos/([a-z0-9-]*)/?$    produto.php?product=$1  [NC,QSA,END]
```

- O parâmetro `?product=xxxx` só pode ser capturado em uma RewriteCond. `%1` faz referência ao grupo 1, da mesma forma que `$1` é usado em uma RewriteRule.
- Certifique-se de definir a flag `[END]` na reescrita, para evitar redirecionamentos infinitos.

---

Carreguei num hospedagem grátis se quiser testá-lo:

1. http://mariano.uphero.com/259605/produtos/nome-produto
2. http://mariano.uphero.com/259605/produto.php?product=NOMEQUEVAISERMANDADO
3. http://mariano.uphero.com/259605/produto.php